# migrate svn local repository to git repository

Tags: git, svn

I have a svn local repository in svn://localhost/monprojet I want to convert it in git repository for example in D:\Repos\Git\test2 . 
I tried svn2git and git svn but always it failed . 
So what's the correct command to do that ? 
thanks .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1st you have to exportyour files from SVN repository.
 step-rightclick on your Repo  then select tortoisesvn => export

Then you have to create a new github repository.
finally you can upload your SVN exported content into GIT repository